# Retrieve all static images in django

Tags: django

In my django app I have a javascript modal.In that modal I want to display all the available static images.I know if there is a single image we can display
it as

```
{% load static %}
      <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/abc.png">
```

But I want to display all the images(they are not fixed) dynamically.How can I write a loop for that.

My desired output (the loop should generate this output)

```
{% load static %}
      <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/abc.png">
      <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/def.png">
      <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/ghi.png">
      .
      .
      .
      <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/xyz.png">
```

**Update 1**
My views.py

```
def show_images(request):

    image_list=[]
    image_folder = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS  #you can add the subdirectory here as well with os.path.join
    for file in image_folder:
        if file.endswith(".png"):
            image_list.append(file)
    # TODO: Read list of existing Int Files and send data to feed the table
    return render(request, myapp/showimages.html', {'brands': image_list})
```

My template:

```
{% for file in brands %}
        <img src="{{file}}" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
```

But with this I am not able to load image at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send all the static images in your context from the view.

```
image_list=[]
static_dirs = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS
for dir in static_dirs:
    for file in os.listdir(dir):
        if file.endswith(".png"):
            image_list.append(file)
```

If you want to traverse the whole static directory, you can do:

```
import os
image_list=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(settings.STATIC_ROOT):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".png"):
            image_list.append(file)
```

You can then return `image_list` in the context and iterate over it in the template.

Update:
For all static files in a particular app, you can do:

```
import os
image_list=[]
app_static_dir = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'appname'),'static'),'images'),'brands')  #appname is your appname and brands is the folder that you mentioned
for file in os.listdir(app_static_dir):
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        image_list.append(file)
```

Comment: Also in settings.py I have STATIC_URL = '/static/'
And then in my appname folder I have "images" folder  inside it there is "brands" folder in which Images are there

Comment: You can use the second code snippet I wrote to get all the files from subdirectories. Use that one. Also, what have you set as your STATICFILES_DIRS in settings file?

Comment: It give this expected `str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list`

Comment: Same error with  `image_folder = os.path.join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS, "images/brands")`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I changed the code now, use the second snippet.

Comment: Also my settings.py is not having `STATICFILES_DIRS` but just has `STATIC_URL`

Comment: Does it have STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: No just `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167563/discussion-between-rookie-123-and-osiris92).

Answer (score 0):

In uploadApp application I have: view.py, displayImg.html.

view.py

```
def uploadImg(request):
    image_list=[]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(settings.MEDIA_ROOT):
        for file in files:
            image_## Heading ##list.append(file)
    return render(request, 'displayImg.html',{'brands': image_list})
#complete.html
```

displayImg.html

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}    
    {% for file in brands %}
        <img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ file }}" width="500px" />
    {% endfor %} 
    {% endblock %}
```

In settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your path to upload images')
```

Answer (score 0):

## view.py

```
def uploadImg(request):
    
    image_list=[]

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(settings.MEDIA_ROOT):
        for file in files:
            image_list.append(file)
    return render(request, 'displayImg.html',{'brands': image_list})
```

displayImg.html

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}    
    {% for file in brands %}
        <img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ file }}" width="500px" />
    {% endfor %} 
    {% endblock %}
```

In sittings.py: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your path to upload images')